# A function that weight a certain constituent part of one of the class (binomial distribution)

Tags: probability, correlation, statistical-significance, binomial-distribution, binary-data

My question concerns ways and tools of how to estimate the "weight" or the "importance" of a certain part of a class in binomial distribution. 
Lets say I have a colony of bacterias, some of them have a positive response on a certain reagent, the remain bacterias - negative. I consider a bacteria as a sum of certain characteristics A, B, C, D. These characteristics are considered as yes/no: yes- if a bacteria has a certain characteristic, no - if a bacteria doesn't have it. My task is to find the characteristics that are important for positive response and that are important for negative response (separately).

I can just use the ration: x/y, where x - number of bacterias with a certain characteristics and with a positive(negative) response, y - number of bacterias with a positive(negative) response. But I also need to take into account how often this characteristic occurred in the other class. For example, I have 100 baceterias, 10 -positive, 90- negative.  Where 8 out of 10 positive bacterias have a characteristic B, so I decide that 8/10 =0.8 - this is an important characteristic for positive response. But 50% of the remain 90 bacterias also have B. Thus, 8/45+8=0.15, and now B seems not to be so important. 
So, how can I find the thresholds, and how shall I biuld this calculation? Is there any specific fomula I can use for these cases?

Will appreciate for any advise, sources etc.